# Show WP category id in json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I made a page that shows some data in json format from a Wordpress database. Now I want show the category id of posts, but it shows all the ids before the object `"ads"`

[image]

My source:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

include ('wp-load.php');


$loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post'));
if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $posts[] = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $post->post_title,
        'post_content' => $post->post_content,
        'guid' => $post->guid,

        'thumbnail' => (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : ''),
        'cats' => the_category_ID(),

    );
endwhile; endif;
echo json_encode(array('ads' => $posts));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows IDs before because of this line
`'cats' => the_category_ID(),`

**What does this function do?**

This function actually echos the category ID ( as it's argument is true by default ).

**How to fix?**

Pass `false` inside `the_category_ID` like this `the_category_ID( false )`

**Corrected code**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

include ('wp-load.php');


$loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post'));
if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $posts[] = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $post->post_title,
        'post_content' => $post->post_content,
        'guid' => $post->guid,

        'thumbnail' => (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : ''),
        'cats' => the_category_ID( false ),

    );
endwhile; endif;
echo json_encode(array('ads' => $posts));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()) : 
    $loop->the_post();
    $posts[] = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $post->post_title,
        'post_content' => $post->post_content,
        'guid' => $post->guid,

        'thumbnail' => (has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : ''),
        'cats' => the_category_ID(),
    );
    ob_clean();
endwhile; endif;
```

use ob clean